# Who creates first nitrogen compounds in the food supply chain

Tags: biochemistry, food

As I understand the food supply chain, organic compounds have to be created from a unlimited source (air, water...).

For instance, I figure that plants transform CO2 from air to organic carbon compounds, mainly carbohydrates, which are then the main source for most other life forms.

But I never heard about a plant turning atmospheric N2 to nitrogen compounds.

Where nitrogen compounds come from, and from which source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are nitrogen fixing bacteria who turn N2 into NH3.  Some are free-living in soil, others live symbiotically with plants.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_fixation

Comment: Also some is fixed by inorganic processes, e.g. lightning converting nitrogen into various oxides.